# ¿Cómo enviar un archivo PDF de un Formulario Html por correo?

Tags: javascript, jspdf

Como enviar un archivo PDF por correo que contenga los datos de un formulario.

Este es código que he intentado:

```
var pdf = new jsPDF(); 
pdf.text(0, 0, 'Hello World!'); 
var pdfBase64 = pdf.output('datauristring'); 
window.plugin.email.open({ to: ['celias1234321@gmail.com'], 
subject: 'New PDF!', 
body: 'Hi there, here is that new PDF you wanted!', 
isHTML: false, 
attachments: [pdfBase64] });
```

pero me arroja el siguiente error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined
```

por favor su apoyo.

Comment: Hola Cesar, para ayudarte mejor, necesitamos más información sobre tu consulta, pon tu código y donde obtienes el error

Comment: Hola, El problema radica en que no encuentro una librería que sea compatible con JS y que me deje crear un archivo pdf atravez de variables de un Form en html y luego enviarla por correo... Utilicé JsPDF pero no me funciono por el siguiente error

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined

Comment: y este es el codigo:  var pdf = new jsPDF();
pdf.text(0, 0, 'Hello World!');
var pdfBase64 = pdf.output('datauristring');

window.plugin.email.open({
  to: ['celias1234321@gmail.com'],
  subject: 'New PDF!',
  body: 'Hi there, here is that new PDF you wanted!',
  isHTML: false,
  attachments: [pdfBase64]
});

Comment: Estas tratando de usar el plugin de correos de [CordovaPDFView](https://github.com/cunneen/cordovaPDFView/tree/master/plugins/de.appplant.cordova.plugin.email-composer)? Estas desarrolando esto desde Phonegap? Has seguido los [pasos de instalacion](https://github.com/cunneen/cordovaPDFView/tree/master/plugins/de.appplant.cordova.plugin.email-composer#installation)?

Comment: Pense que el codigo ere de jsPDF, por que yo actualmente uso xampp con php pero queria general los archivos con javascript